# trouble with arrays and array lists

Tags: java, arrays

This is for class homework. She is making us use array and array list in two parts. Basically she is showing us how using arraylist is alot easier than arrays.

I am having alot of trouble getting the array part to work.

1. Create a class called CustomerLister1 with a main method that instantiates an array of String objects called customerName. The array should have room for six String objects. Use an initializer list to put the following names into the array:

   - Chris
   - Lois
   - Meg
   - Peter
   - Stewie
2. Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names. What is displayed for the last array element? Why is it that value?
3. Add the Strings "Meg" and "Brian" into index 3, and 4, respectively, so that the array contains the following elements:

   - Chris
   - Lois
   - Meg
   - Meg
   - Brian
   - Peter
   - Stewie
4. Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names.
5. Write a second, traditional for loop that checks each element for the String “Meg”, if found in the array, remove it, shift the remaining elements, and display the array of names. Are both instances of "Meg" removed correctly from the array?

This is my code

```
public class CustomerLister1
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
String[] customerName = new String[7];
customerName[0] = "Chris";
customerName[1] = "Lois";
customerName[2] = "Meg";
customerName[3] = "Peter";
customerName[4] = "Stewie";

for (int i = customerName.length-1;i > 3; i--)
{
    customerName[i] = customerName[i - 2];
}
customerName[3] = "Meg";
customerName[4] = "Brian";

for (int m = 0; m <= customerName.length-1; m++)
{
if(customerName[m].equals("Meg"))
{
for(int j = m;j < customerName.length;j++)
{
    if(j < customerName.length-2) {
        customerName[j]= customerName[j+1];
    } else {
        customerName[j]="";
    }
}
m--;
}

for (String element : customerName)
{
    System.out.println(element);
}

}
}
}
```

The output is wrong though it removes both the megs and then adds brian peter then two empty lines and then stewie. I need the empty lines to be gone and the output to print continuously.

Comment: Have you tried to understand what are you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. It uses an aditional counter to know when you should put the `""` in the array instead of shifting the next element.

```
int customerSize = 7;
for (int m = 0; m <= customerName.length-1; m++)
{
    if(customerName[m].equals("Meg"))
    {
        customerSize--;
        for(int j = m;j < customerName.length;j++)
        {
            if(j >= customerSize)
                customerName[j] = "";
            else
                customerName[j] = customerName[j+1];    
        }
        m--;

        for (String element : customerName)
        {
            if(! element.equals(""))
                System.out.println(element);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Chris
Lois
Meg
Brian
Peter
Stewie

Chris
Lois
Brian
Peter
Stewie
```